# Animate On Scroll doesn't work/hides div

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

trying to have a div fade up on "entry" of viewport, using https://github.com/michalsnik/aos

However all it does is hide the div.

In the head I've referenced the aos.js file as well as inserted:

```
<script>
AOS.init({
easing: 'ease-in-out-sine'
});
</script>
```

On the div which I want to animate:

```
        <div class="wrap" data-aos="fade-up">
```

Can anybody tell me what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

data-scrollreveal="enter left after 0s over 1s"

you can put this, and it will enter from left after you come to that area you use it like this

```
<div class="myDiv" data-scrollreveal="enter left after 0s over 1s"> Some text </div>
```